# Including part of html file in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am a newbie to web2py and want to do this..
I am doing a presentation web application , in which users can view presentations(`reveal.js` files) of a number of topics. These presentations contain head tags and scripts which are same to all.. so i thought of creating a view called `default/presentation.html` and then store all the presentations as `html/xml` files and display them inside the `learn.html` file (these files contain only part of file, stuff within the body tag). But I have tried a lot of stuff, but still could not get id due to web2py's default escaping feature. Please help me out with the most simplest way.

P.S. This is an awesome community where i took most of my programming lessons. Thanks in advance.

Update: thanks a lot guys. Found a solution finally using xml parsing with etree. In my view,

```
 {{for i in tree: }}
    {{=TAG    [i.tag]    (i.text)}}
    {{pass }}
```

Guess what? Works amazing!

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where/how are you storing the html files? Is default/presentation.html the outermost layout template, or is it contained within another layout (e.g., /views/layout.html)? How are you serving the presentations (e.g., via a single `presentation()` function within default.py, with a URL arg indicating the particular presentation to serve)? Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that you want to have one template to wrap the text of the presentations into? If that is the case, [this should explain it](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to insert some HTML into a page without it being escaped, you can use the [`XML()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05#XML) helper:

```
{{=XML(your_html)}}
```

If you want to include the contents of a file, you can do:

```
{{include 'path/to/file'}}
```

Note, the path is relative to the application's /views folder, so if it is outside of that folder, you can start the path with `../`.